# Good network for binomial classification of continuous and categorical dataset

Tags: data-science-model, python-3.x

I have a continuous variable from which I want to predict 1 simple event, to increase my odds, I created more 2 continuous variables that combined make the main variable and a lot of dummy vars.

Target variable to predict only is positive 0.001 percent of rows.

Which type of architecture do you think is suitable?
Should I make some adjustments, like 2 different types of inputs (regression and classification) or some weight's?

Update : to downsize the imbalance in targets I sliced the dataframe based on an Ocorrence, and I only have data that is in that Ocorrence. So yes I think I created samples of the time series, don't know which model|architecture is better for that classification & regression problem.

Comment: What do you mean by regression and classification inputs? These terms describe the type of model, and you've already said you need a classification model.

Comment: Output is binary classification, but inputs are continuous variables and dummy vars ...

Comment: Updated  the question @Lynn